# generating .so file instead of .exe in qt4.7 on linux

Tags: linux, qt4, qt-creator

I have built a simple GUI application in QtCreator-2.0.1 i have following files:

```
first.pro  
first.pro.user  
main.cpp  
mainwindow.cpp  
mainwindow.h  
mainwindow.ui
```

If I run `qmake` and `make` it gives me an executable. Is it possible to generate a `.so` file from these files? if so, can someone tell me the steps to be followed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to build a shared library ? A plugin ?

When you created your project with *Qt Creator*, which kind of project did you choose ?

In your case, I guess you wanted to choose `Other Project->C++ Library` (you can then choose if you want a `shared library` or a `Qt 4 plugin`.

Anyway, from your project, I guess you'll have to change the template in your `.pro` and put :

```
TEMPLATE = lib
```